# how to check in an array whether it has a key:value or not?

Tags: javascript

```
  var people =[{title:'Alan', hasChild:true},
        {title:'Alice', hasDetail:true},
        {title:'Amos', header'A'},
        {title:'Alonzo'},
        {title:'Brad'},
        {title:'Brent'},    
        {title:'Billy'},    
        {title:'Brenda'},   
        {title:'Callie'},
        {title:'Cassie'},   
        {title:'Chris'}];
```

I want to check in this array, whether it contains a key,value `header:value` in it or not. I want to check this for each elements.

Comment: I can't even see an array there. Please try to post some **real** code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This should do it:**

```
for (var i = 0, c = people.length;i < c;i++) {
    if (people[i].header) {
        // yay
        // not sure wether you want to check the value as well
        // but if that is the case, you'd do this
        if (people[i].header == 'A') {
            // do some more stuff
        }
    } else {
        // nay
    }
}
```

Comment: Should check for the actual value too: `if(people[i].header === 'A')`

Comment: @Rudie not sure if that is an actual requirement. The OP is quite vague but I think he only wants to see if the parameter is *present*

Comment: He's talking about `key:value`, so I think he wants to know/check the value too. Vague indeed.

Comment: if I am not missing anything, will it not show `undefined` error if there is no `header` key present in the object ?

Comment: @naiquevin when no `header` key is present, the `if` statement will evaluate to `false`, resulting in no error.

Comment: Yes... i missed it Rudie... if it contains the value header == 'A' and similaraly for header =='B' and so on

Comment: @John added the value check to the answer.

Comment: @Aron Rotteveel
Can i make it more generic, if i have like header:'b', header:'c'.. etc etc.... i am adding the value header:'a' based on the first character of title

Comment: @John you should be good to go with the answer as-is: I'm sure you can get things working if you edit and complement the code example yourself :)

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i){
    if(array[i]["header"])
        //Do stuff with the header
    else
        //Do stuff without it
}
```

This should work... Though you've got an error in the element with the header - it should be `header:'A'`, with the `:`

Answer (score 1):

you can check if it is defined or not using `typeof`

```
for (var i in arr) {    
    if (typeof arr[i].header !== 'undefined') {
       //key present
    }  else {
       //key not present
    }  
}
```